# Nginx status information of virtual hosts

Tags: nginx, monitoring, virtualhost

I want to monitor each nginx virtual hosts(I have multiple nginx config for different domain) and found nginx module [ngx_http_stub_status_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html)

But seems this module is for displaying server wide status not by per virtual hosts. Is there any solution to gather vhost stat information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [Nginx virtual host traffic status module](https://github.com/vozlt/nginx-module-vts) however, it only works for compiled Nginx. Simply compile your nginx with this module and add the following directives to your vhosts or as per the documentation:

```
 location /status {
            vhost_traffic_status_display;
            vhost_traffic_status_display_format html;
        }
```

Hope it meet your needs.

Regards,

Kheshav

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer! I was wondering what would happen if I compile nginx again when it's already installed from the repository?

Comment: Well that depends on your configuration and modules you installed. A better approach would be to compile the Nginx same version as the RPM one. Also I would recommend that you backup your configurations etc.
If the answer meet the requirements of your question and solved your problem please do vote it as an answer,

Comment: is there a way/workaround in 2021 to use this module for nginx installed with yum?